# Update MYSQL Table if Name is Already In the DB

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a database that stores user details, I want users to be able to update their details if their name matches.

Currently I submit details to the database like this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO gdpr_info (name, email, phone, comments, phoneout, emailout, postout, phonein, emailin, postin) VALUES ('".$yourName."','".$yourEmail."', '".$yourPhone."', '".$comments."','".$phoneout."','".$emailout."','".$postout."','".$phonein."','".$emailin."','".$postin."')";
```

How would I go about updating the user row ONLY if the name matches for example if a user called 'Robbie Fowler' wanted to update his email he would go to the form, type his name and anything else he puts in after would update his row instead of creating a new row.

I've seen the duplicate key option, but on the form there are checkboxes so I'm worried that if I use that most of the forms will have at least one duplicate key due to the checkbox and it will update the wrong row.

Can you specific which column must be duplicated to update the row?

Comment: SELECT/WHERE clause

Comment: ALL of your columns in are in the primary key? I would say that THAT is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If he is the user want to update his details I guess you the use the mysql update query to update how this will done is 
       First fetch the user from the db . The user can be the logged in user who wants to update
      Then update the email column like this
 `UPDATE table-name SET column ='.$_POST['newvalue'].' WHERE namecolumn ='.$loggedINuser.';`

Or if you want to change the bame as you said in the question with the name input and the new email then 
 `UPDATE table-name SET column ='..$_POST['newvalue'].' WHERE namecolumn ='.$_POST['name'].';`

And also I guess there can be only one primary fields in a table so just look for that the You can have multiple unique columns but one primary column (id column is recommended for that )

Hope this will work